# gulp useref remove files from pipeline

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Is there a way to not output the gulp.src file? My goal is to bundle javascript only and output .js only, not html.

In `base.html` the following blocks are used to bundle Javascript with gulp-useref:

```
<!-- build:js app.core.js -->
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}etherflex/js/vendor/conditionizr_4.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}etherflex/js/app/conditionizr.detects.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}etherflex/js/app/conditionizr.config.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}etherflex/js/vendor/mootools-core_1.4.5.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

The gulp task

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var gzip = require('gulp-gzip');
var useref = require('gulp-useref');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');

module.exports = function (path) {
    return gulp.src('templates/**/*.html')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: notify.onError("Error: <%= error.message %>")}))
        .pipe(useref({
            searchPath: path.source,
            transformPath: function(filePath) {
                return filePath.replace('{{ STATIC_URL }}/','')
            }
        }))
        .pipe(changed(path.build + 'js'))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: ".min",
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build + 'js'))
        .pipe(notify("Javascript concatenated, minified and gzip compressed: <%= file.relative %>"))
        .pipe(gzip())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build + 'js'));
};
```

The goal is simply to read the block comments in base.html only and output the bundled javascript `app.core.js`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could always just prefix the `gulp.dest` with `gulpif`, eg `.pipe(gulpif('*.js', gulp.dest(path.build + 'js')))`

Comment: Duh. I didn't think of that. Thanks a million, I was struggling with this for hours. The simplest solution didn't even cross my mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment, you can simply use `gulp-if` to filter the stream for `gulp.dest`.

```
.pipe(gulpif('*.js', gulp.dest(path.build + 'js')))
```

Comment: Thanks @phil. Dead simple and perfect solution. I had no idea `gulp-if` had so many uses. Powerful plugin for sure.

Comment: @nfq you can also combine it with lazypipe for some really complex stream manipulation